# Why is 'SHOW WARNINGS' query issued here? (JPA/Hibernate/MySQL)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hikaricp

We are refactoring the persistence layer of a Java application from JDBC Template to JPA/Hibernate.

I am profiling the SQL statements being issued to the database and I see "SHOW WARNINGS" is issued many, many times.  According to JProfiler the "SHOW WARNINGS" is accounting for a considerable amount of 'inherent time'.

**What could cause SHOW WARNINGS to be issued so frequently?**

This SHOW WARNINGS was NOT previously issued when using Jdbc Template.

Below is the part of our stack relevant to persistence.  The only change here is the introduction of JPA/Hibernate.

- JPA / Hibernate: 4.3.6
- MySQL driver: 5.1.33
- MySQL database: 5.6.20
- JDBC Connection Pool: HikariCP-2.3.2

EDIT: Here's a sample stack trace of when SHOW WARNINGS is issued.

```
com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings()
com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementJavassistProxy.getWarnings()
org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult()
com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.getSingleResult(javax.persistence.Query)
com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult()
com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.uniqueResult(com.mysema.query.types.Expression)
org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Object[ ])
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.findOne(com.mysema.query.types.Predicate)
```

Comment: did you stumble into how to suppress warnings ?

Comment: Are you running MySQL with the `--show-warnings` option?

Comment: Can you post the xml configuration of your persistence-unit?

Comment: @Duncan, I don't think this is related to MySQL config because when I run on same DB with previous persistence strategy the SHOW WARNINGS are not issued.  I'll see if I can add pu xml.  but are you aware of any JPA/Hibernate setting which could influence this?

Comment: I think it could be your auto-commit setting. In JDBC you probably explicitly set this to false, but Hibernate sets this to true by default. The SHOW WARNINGS could be Hibernate performing the auto-commits.

Comment: In the configuration of our datasource for our PostgreSQL database we have the property: `<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>`. Not sure if the same property could be used for your MySQL driver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is **WHY** show warnings is being issued:
`org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.handleAndClearWarnings()` is calling `com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.getWarnings()`.

A comment in the Hibernate source code says:

> "See HHH-9174.  Statement#getWarnings can be an expensive call for
>   many JDBC libs.  Don't do it unless the log level would actually allow
>   a warning to be logged."

I upped the logging level on logback.xml on "org.hibernate" to ERROR. Profiling shows SHOW WARNINGS query is NO LONGER being issued.

This has made a marginal improvement in performance.

I would appreciate any input as to whether it is actually a good idea to disable SHOW WARNINGS here.

Comment: **I would suggest it's a good idea to disable for a production server.** It could prove valuable in a dev/test environment and catch things like truncation due to data type mismatches but if that's happening you have app/schema mismatches and probably should look at preventing that from happening rather than catching it after you've lost data. For some context/data on the performance issues that I was seeing which lead me to find this answer: [pt-query-digest analysis via tcpdump, load @ 7.8k QPS](http://pastebin.com/N2i1uBHQ)

Comment: Hi Justin, any chance you could share the important part of your logback.xml ? I have the same problem while <logger name="org.hibernate" level="ERROR" /> is present in my logback.xml

Comment: <logger name="org.hibernate" level="info" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi" level="error" />
 <logger name="org.hibernate.engine.internal" level="error" />

Comment: Do you know how to raise the log level for the [plain old default vanilla Hibernate settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44211525/616460) (i.e. not using Logback, so no `logback.xml`)? Btw, of interest: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9174; that's where the ability for `SHOW WARNINGS` to be disabled based on log level was originally added. Also re: your last paragraph, I don't know, but lots of blogs about this issue talk about disabling it in production servers in general, and comments on said blogs support that as a best practice, too.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of this works on payara & log4j, hibernate is still polluting DB with 'show warnings' statements